# Testing cookie for review

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

im new in cookie using php. im having a problem in changing its value. i created a test so i can simulate what i want to do, i cant. so i want to ask if this is possible.

so here is my sample code:

```
<?php
setcookie('name', 'test1', (time()+30*60), '/');
echo $_COOKIE['name'];

setcookie('name', 'test2', (time()+30*60), '/');
echo $_COOKIE['name'];

?>
```

the ouput is: 
    test2test2

my desired output is:
    test1test2

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Working of cookies in every language same and is like :
1) Cookies are created by script and being stored in client's system.
2) if there is any cookie in client's system belongs to requested url is been sent through HTTP request.
3) Only after step (2) script can read cookie.

In your senario: when script runs 
setcookie('name', 'test1', (time()+30*60), '/'); //cookie is set as name= test1

echo $_COOKIE['name'];//But script is unable to find cookie named as name because its not be sent through HTTP request at first time.

setcookie('name', 'test2', (time()+30*60), '/');// cookies is overwritten by test2

echo $_COOKIE['name'];//But script is unable to find cookie named as name because its not be sent through HTTP request at first time.

Now it we refresh the page cookie name=test2 is being sent through HTTP request
and script will read  $_COOKIE['name'] as test2.